# Node (Sync/Synchronize) cannot find fibers binaries

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-fibers

I know, that many have already had this problem and I tried every solution I could find, but nothing helped...
I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31215400/nodejs-sync-cannot-find-fibers-binaries) question, but it didn't work for me :(

The problem:

It says:
node_modules\fibers\bin\win32-ia32-53\fibers.node is missing.
when trying to launch any Electron-edge project that uses require('fibers').

Versions and other information:
I do have win32-ia32-48 and win32-ia32-57 folders.
Electron.exe is 32-bit
The .node files in are 32-bit as well
npm fibers is at version 2.0.0

[This](https://i.gyazo.com/55bb7b058d0f33cbe09abb0948cff787.png) is (supposedly) my node version: (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"2.13.3"})

However, I installed the "Latest LTS Version: v6.11.1 (includes npm 3.10.10)".

I have no idea what to do. I tried for 3 days straight to get fibers to work (or sync/syncronize for that matter), but nothing helped.

Comment: Did you run `npm install fibers`?

Comment: Yes I did. It's installed at version 2.0.0 (that one includes the -48 and -57 folders, but it searches for -53 instead)

Comment: The numerical prefixes are related to different Node.js versions, so if you updated/changed your Node, you need to reinstall `fibers`.

Comment: @robertklep Well I reinstalled fibers a bunch of times now and also reinstalled Nodejs in various versions and bit-versions

Comment: This thread might provide some useful info: https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1259

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so for anyone reading this, here's my solution. Big thanks to robertklep for the link to that github issue.

The problem was, that (for whatever reason) the fibers module was built for the wrong version. The version has to be identical with the expected module version.

In order to get that, you have to rebuild the module yourself.
If electron-rebuild doesn't automatically get the settings right, you can specify the correct --arch (ia32/x64) and --version (electron version here) yourself. --force might help as well, at least it shouldn't have any negative side effects.

[Full list of arguments.](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild#cli-arguments)

My final command looked something like this:

```
electron-rebuild.cmd --arch ia32 --version 1.6.11 --force
```

Be sure to install Fibers >before< rebuilding it as well as the module requireing Fibers.